# How can I remove a device from my Gmail account

Tags: gmail, account-management

I'm trying to delete a mobile phone associated to my Gmail account. The number on the mobile phone used to be issued to me by my former company. How can I do that?

Comment: Are you saying that this phone number is stored in your Gmail/Google account? Or the device is using an "authorised application"?

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to remove/change your mobile number associated with your Gmail. Here is the way from [Accounts Help](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/27442?hl=en):

> **Edit your basic account information**
>
> Phone number
>
> 1. Sign in to [My Account](https://myaccount.google.com/).
> 2. In the "Personal info & privacy" section, choose **Your personal info**.
> 3. Select **Phone**.
> 4. Follow the onscreen instructions.